# Integral with lower bound only

Tags: integration

I'm confused about this equation because it doesn't have an upper bound. can you help me to elaborate on this equation, or what should I read to understand this equation?

[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAWxV.jpg)

Comment: Do you know measure theory?

Comment: i dont know, im sorry, can you see the picture? because it shown error on my pc

Comment: I can see it, that is why I asked the question. You better learn measure theory, Lebesgue integral in particular, before dealing with such problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.